# Configure IBM HTTP server for Jboss Application server

Tags: webserver, jboss7.x, ibmhttpserver

Recently we have moved our application from websphere to jboss application server. 
IBM Http server (IHS) has front ended(proxy) the websphere application server.
Now we want to make changes to httpd.conf to make the IHS to front end the jboss. So whats the configuration to be done at IHS server to act like reverse proxy for JBOSS application server?

Answer (score 1):

There's really no reason to do this, because IBM HTTP Server is only ever supported when it's used with IBM software that it was bundled with.

If you do do it, you're nearly alone in doing so and w/o the assistance of IBM.

Technically, you could use mod_proxy_balancer and mod_proxy_http just like any other Apache-based server, but they're not as well maintained because they are only used in one very obscure/withdrawn IBM product that bundles IHS.  It's a basic proxy configuration for Apache and not really worth going into detail here.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for JBoss AS/Wildfly application server proxy for you is Apache HTTP Server with [mod_cluster](http://modcluster.io).

## Community

You can give it a try with Fedora: [mod_cluster package](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/mod_cluster)
And there is an example on how to compile it from sources and configure it with Apache HTTP Server from scratch: [example, recorded terminal session](http://modcluster.io/examples/#apache-http-server-examples). It also operates on Windows and Solaris.

## Why mod_cluster over mod_jk/mod_proxy?

The main benefit of mod_cluster over mod_proxy*balancer / mod_jk solutions is that both JBoss AS and Wildfly contain mod_cluster subsystems that automatically report deployed contexts and life cycle events to the mod_cluster balancer in Apache HTTP Server. JBoss AS/Wildfly workers join Apache HTTP Server balancer automatically, you don't have to reconfigure anything in your httpd.conf nor restart httpd when you add another JBoss AS/Wildfly worker.

Current load report is also a part of these service messages. One may use several different load metrics within JBoss AS/Wildfly, e.g. heap utilization, CPU load, number of currently open sessions, or one could easily implement a custom load metric.

The result is a high-throughput dynamic load balancer that takes into account actual utilization of your JBoss AS/Wildfly workers.

## Commercial support

If you need a fully supported solution for mod_cluster balancer, both [Red Hat JBoss Web Server](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/web-server), i.e. Apache HTTP Server, mod_cluster, OpenSSL, Tomcat 7, Tomcat 8, mod_jk, ModSecurity, and [Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform (EAP)](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/application-platform), i.e. application server built on Wildfly 10+ or AS 7+, entitle you to fully supported mod_cluster balancer fronting either Tomcat workers or EAP workers.

**Full Disclosure:** I am an engineer at Red Hat